# AUCTeX - removing an environment from auto-complete list

Tags: latex, auctex, auto-complete-mode

I use the auto-complete feature of LaTeX-environment often.  I'd like to be able to remove entries from the auto-complete list.  I usually need to use the packages amsmath and amsthm, which introduce lots of environments I don't use. I'd prefer not to have them in my auto-complete list (so that I can type fewer characters to find the environment I want).  Is there a way to have this happen automatically after I open a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare macros and environments you don't need using `TeX-declare-expert-macros` and `LaTeX-declare-expert-environments` and then set `TeX-complete-expert-commands` to `nil`.